# Serialize C# objects to XML - Fastest way?

Tags: .net, xml, serialization, xml-serialization

I've an application that serialize c# objects to xml file. I'm currently using the .Net XmlSerializer.

The problem I've, is that I need to serialize ~8000 main nodes(with 4-10 subnodes each time), and it takes me currently something like 15-20min to serialize them all.

I've to keep the same XML output, because the file are read by another program than mine, and I cannot make them change the way they read the file.

I've made some search, and I found a lot of comparison, but they all involve to use protobuf-net, which has a binary serialization.

So my question is: how can I improve this serialization time? Another serializer? Adding more attributes to my model(currently I've only XmlName, same for lists).

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the below link there are few tips to improve XML serialization performance

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650685.aspx

If it is possible for you to change the logic of your component I would use a database to store such a big XML as serialization has not been made to store very large XML file

Comment: I've already all XmlIgnore, then end format contains only needed data. I've to put them in a file, because I've to push this file on a FTP server, which will distribute this file to other services. You think that if I implement mySelf the ISerializable method, it will be faster than the [Serializable] attribute?

Comment: it will be a bit faster has stated also on the link above - Implementing ISerializable.

Comment: Yeah but any idea about how it will improve? Because if it's to win 30 seconds on my 20 min, it's doesn't worth it.

Comment: you won't improve more than couple of minutes as the bottle neck in your case is the size of the XML

Answer (score 0):

Since the bottle neck might be the big string handling you might want to consider hand-writing code that writes directly to FileStream. 
If you are adventurous you can also try to generate the code writing IGenerator for [CGbR Project](https://github.com/Toxantron/CGbR). But this only makes sense if you have many different classes.