# Convert Generic List of objects to SqlXml

Tags: c#, xml, xmldocument, generic-list

Please do not mark as duplicate without reading through as I have been googling this and searching on stackoverflow but I cant find exactly what I want.

How do I convert a generic list of objects in c# into data type SqlXml.

Note that I am not looking to convert into xml string output.

I need this output type specifically so I can pass it in as SqlXml parameter to a stored procedure.

Comment: Possible duplicate [Serialize C# objects to XML - Fastest way?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14436025/serialize-c-sharp-objects-to-xml-fastest-way)

Comment: Lol. I knew someone was gonna mark this as duplicate without reading through cuz it looks like other questions but it is subtly different

Comment: Then try a different serializer like [XSerializer](http://nuget.org/packages/XSerializer/).

Comment: If XML Serialization is too slow, have you tried simply iterating your list and creating the XmlWriter/XmlDocument on the fly?

Comment: @adam-plocher Have a look at my edit. Ill try out your XmlDocument constructor approach

Comment: @mike try taking a stab at this.

Comment: any reason why you don't want an XDocument?

Comment: I have never used XDocument. Could you propose it as a solution with an example? If it is fast and uses the input list in a type safe manner, I'll accept your answer

Comment: just updated my answer

Comment: My apologies @keith-nicholas. Please look at the question as I realized I need something slightly different –

Comment: Serialize to a `MemoryStream`, set the stream back to position 0, then instantiate the `SqlXml` passing the stream.

Comment: @John-Saunders. Post that as an answer. I'll try it out tomorrow morning first thing.If it works right, Ill accept. I know I said the same thing to Keith Nicholas but I'll do better this time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on John Saunders' suggestion

```
MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(TypeOfObjectToBeConverted));
XmlTextWriter xmlTextWriter = new XmlTextWriter(memoryStream, Encoding.UTF8);
xs.Serialize(xmlTextWriter, objectToBeConverted);
memoryStream = (MemoryStream)xmlTextWriter.BaseStream;
memoryStream.Position = 0;
System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlXml obj = new System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlXml(memoryStream);
```